# PHP Switch statement comparison issues

Tags: php, html, mysql

so I have a variable called multiplier that contains a certain value depending on what the user registered with. What I am trying to write here is

If multiplier is equal to "sedentary" then give it the value of `$sedmultiplier`

If multiplier is equal to "lightly" then give it the value of `$lightmultiplier`

Im stuck on this, can't seem to figure out how this would be written.

```
  switch ($multiplier==) {
      case "sedentary":
         $multiplier=$sedmultiplier;
         break;
     case "lightly":
         $multiplier=$lightmultiplier;
          break;
      case "moderately":
         $multiplier=$modmultiplier;
         break;
      case "very":
         $multiplier=$verymultiplier;
         break;
      case "extremely":
         $multiplier=$extrememultiplier;
         break;
      default:
          multiplier==0;
  }
```

Comment: You need to remove the `==` on the first line. And you can make this a lot easier if you use an array to store the keys and values.

Comment: why r u using ==? replace this `$multiplier==` with `$multiplier`

Comment: In your `default:` part, you're missing the `$` in front of the `multiplier` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Replace **$multiplier==** with **$multiplier** and your code should work.

Like this :

```
switch ($multiplier) 
{
  case "sedentary":
     $multiplier=$sedmultiplier;
     break;
 case "lightly":
     $multiplier=$lightmultiplier;
      break;
  case "moderately":
     $multiplier=$modmultiplier;
     break;
  case "very":
     $multiplier=$verymultiplier;
     break;
  case "extremely":
     $multiplier=$extrememultiplier;
     break;
  default:
      $multiplier==0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like @jeroen suggested, I would set the multipliers as an array instead. This way you can reuse them and add/remove multipliers more easily.

```
// Create the array with name => multiplier
$multipliers = [
    "sedentary"  => $sedmultiplier,
    "lightly"    => $lightmultiplier,
    "moderately" => $modmultiplier,
    "very"       => $verymultiplier,
    "extremely"  => $extrememultiplier,
    // ... just add more here, if needed...
];

// Check if we have a key with the current name.
// If we do, return the value, otherwise return 0 as default.
$multiplier = array_key_exists($multiplier, $multipliers)
    ? $multipliers[$multiplier]
    : 0;
```

Comment: Nicely explained :-)

Comment: What does the => do? I looked into arrays but examples dont show this operator.  Could anyone explain this a little further? :)

Comment: @PMG - If you looked into PHP arrays, it's impossible that you didn't see `=>` like so:. `$array = ['key' => 'value'];`. Please check: [PHP Manual about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Check the first example.